# How to integrate Qwipi with woo commerce wordpress

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce, payment-gateway

I want to attach Qwipi  merchant with WordPress (woo commerce).
I searched a lot but didn't get any plugin.
I tried to get plugin but there isn't one.
Is there any way of doing this?

Answer (score -1):

We recently built a QWIPI payment module for OpenCart - there isn't currently one for WooCommerce but we would be willing to make one for you if interested? Drop me an email - ben@weboptic.co.uk